# Preserve new line when saving data

Tags: python, json

When I try to save this json data [1] into a file, python doesn't preserve the new lines of the json data. I want to preserve it. How I do this?

[1] Code to save the data

```
data = {
  "queuecapacity": "0.0",
  "maps": "9",
  "byteswritten": "44089526",
  "time": "52.5484039783",
  "mem": 49222464,
  "bytesread": "1102253727",
  "cpu": 32000
}

 with open(path, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 8):

Pass in the indent option to json.dumps()

```
out_file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump,

> If indent is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, or negative, will only insert newlines. None (the default) selects the most compact representation.

Also, you can rewrite your call with `json.dump()` if you already have the file object,

```
json.dump(data, out_file, indent=4)
```